# Application.cfc vs Application.cfm which has more priority in different folders

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, application.cfc, application.cfm

In my application root folder, I have an `Application.cfc` file. In a subfolder, there is an `Application.cfm`. When I call a script in the subfolder which Application file executes: `Application.cfc` or `Application.cfm`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call templates in the subfolder then the `Application.cfm` in the subfolder gets executed.

Answer (score 2):

Application.cfm gets executed and to learn more about the order of execution.
[From the documentation:](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/developing-cfml-applications/designing-and-optimizing-a-coldfusion-application/structuring-an-application.html)

**How ColdFusion finds and process application definition pages**

> ColdFusion uses the following rules to locate and process the
>   Application.cfc, Application.cfm, and OnRequestEnd.cfm pages that
>   define application-specific elements. The way ColdFusion locates these
>   files helps determine how you structure an application.
>
> Each time ColdFusion processes a page request it does the following:
>
> 1. When ColdFusion starts processing the request, it does the following:
>
>    - It searches the page's directory for a file named Application.cfc. If    one exists, it creates a new instance of the CFC, processes the 
>        initial events, and stops searching. (ColdFusion creates a new
>        instance of the CFC and processes its initialization code for each
>        request.)
>    - If the requested page's directory does not have an Application.cfc    file, it checks the directory for an Application.cfm file. If one
>        exists, ColdFusion logically includes the Application.cfm page at the 
>        beginning of the requested page and stops searching further.
>    - If the requested page's directory does not have an Application.cfc or    Application.cfm file, ColdFusion searches up the directory tree
>        and    checks each directory first for an Application.cfc file and
>        then, if    one is not found, for an Application.cfm page, until it
>        reaches the    root directory (such as C:). When it finds an
>        Application.cfc or    Application.cfm file, it processes the page and
>        stops searching.
> 2. ColdFusion processes the requested page's contents.
> 3. When the request ends, ColdFusion does the following:
>
>    - If you have an Application.cfc, ColdFusion processes the CFC's onRequestEnd method
>        and releases the CFC instance.
>    - If you do not have an
>        Application.cfc, but do have an Application.cfm page, ColdFusion looks
>        for an OnRequestEnd.cfm in the same directory as the Application.cfm
>        page ColdFusion uses for the current page. ColdFusion does not search
>        beyond that directory, so it does not run an OnRequestEnd.cfm page
>        that resides in another directory. Also, the OnRequestEnd.cfm page
>        does not run if there is an error or an exception on the application
>        page, or if the application page executes the cfabort or cfexit tag.
>
> The following rules determine how ColdFusion processes application
>   pages and settings:
>
> - ColdFusion processes only one Application.cfc or Application.cfm page    for each request. If a ColdFusion page has a cfinclude tag
>     pointing    to an additional ColdFusion page, ColdFusion does not
>     search for an    Application.cfc or Application.cfm page when it
>     includes the    additional page.
> - If a ColdFusion page has a cfapplication tag, it first processes any    Application.cfc or Application.cfm, and then processes the
>     cfapplication tag. The tag overrides the settings from the
>     application files, including the application name and the behaviors
>     set by the cfapplication tag attributes.
> - You can have multiple Application.cfc files, Application.cfm files,    and cfapplication tags that use the same application name. In this
>     case, all pages that have the same name share the same application
>     settings and Application scope and set and get all the variables in
>     this scope. ColdFusion uses the parameter settings of the
>     cfapplication tag or the most recently processed file, if the
>     settings, such as the session time-out, differ among the files.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are server settings which also influence the way which application.cfc/cfm file is executed.
In the

> Application.cfc/Application.cfm lookup order
>
> Select the order in which ColdFusion searches for Application.cfm or >Application.cfc if it is not found in the current project folder. You can >set ColdFusion to search as follows:
>
> - default search order: ColdFusion looks for an >Application.cfc/Application.cfm file from the current folder until the >system root directory. On Windows, this could be C:\ and on UNIX, /opt.
> - till web root: ColdFusion looks for an Application.cfc/Application.cfm >file from the current folder till web root.
> - in web root: ColdFusion looks for an Application.cfc/Application.cfm file >in the current folder or web root.

[CFIDE SETTINGS](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/configuring-administering/using-the-coldfusion-administrator.html)